# How to return data from a dialog fragment to activity adapter?

Tags: java, android

I am showing a Dialog Fragment from my Activity Adapter, I have one EditText and some other views in Dialog fragment. And I have to return some data directly to Activity and the Adapter clicking the update button in Dialog Dragment I can pass data to the Activity, but can't pass data to adapter.My adapter listener is not working

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment 
  {

    private OnItemUpdateListenerDialog onItemUpdateListenerDialog;


    private void SetValues(final CartItemDetail item) {

    buttUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           setValue=editSet.getText().toString();//get value from editText

          onItemUpdateListenerDialog.onItemUpdateRequest(addItemToCart(item.getDataOne(), item.getDataTwo()));//listner for activity
           onSetChangeListnerDialog.returnData(setValue);//listner for adapter


            dismiss();

        }
    });


    }
     public interface OnItemUpdateListenerDialog {
    void onItemUpdateRequest(JSONObject jsonObject);

 }

public void setOnItemUpdateListenerDialog(OnItemUpdateListenerDialog onItemUpdateListener) {
    this.onItemUpdateListenerDialog = onItemUpdateListenerDialog;

}

public interface OnSetChangeListenerDialog {
    void returnData(String result);
}
 public  void setOnSetChangeListenerDialog(OnSetChangeListenerDialog onSetUpdateRequest) {
    onSetChangeListnerDialog = onSetChangeListnerDialog;
}

  @Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        this.onItemUpdateListenerDialog = (OnItemUpdateListenerDialog)activity;//activit listner
           this.onSetChangeListnerDialog = (OnSetChangeListenerDialog)activity;//adapter listner
    }
    catch (final ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnCompleteListener");
    }
}
}



}
```

> My Adapter class

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> 
implements View.OnClickListener,MyDialogFragment.OnSetChangeListenerDialog{
     @Override
      public void returnData(String result) {
    setValue = result;
      }

       }
```

Comment: Are you starting new activity on click

Comment: no..just returning data if user edit dialog fragment edititext through call back

Comment: i think in my onAttach method problem,

Comment: i am getting this error  java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.app.MyActivity@2677107 must implement OnCompleteListener..

Comment: Try to use an external interface

Comment: ok,can u check my onAttach method?i initialized my activity and adapter listner in onattach..when i click update button i want to call two listners at same time

Comment: Does your activity implement both the interface which you are trying to get in onAttach method of the dialog? If not then you will get exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to define an external simple interface :

**Returning.java**

```
public interface Returning {
    void return_value(String value);
}
```

**MyDialogFragment.java**

```
public class MyDialogFragment {
    private Returning returning;

    buttUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            returning= ((Returning ) context);
            returning.return_value("everything");
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

**MyAdapter.java**

```
public class MyAdapter implements Returning {
    // ...
    @Override
    public void return_value(String value) {
        setValue = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: can u say how can i set this value to my view holder textview?

Comment: the best way is refreshing your activity with new data @user8838050

Answer (score 0):

Add this method to your dialog class

`public interface EditDialogListener {
        void receiveResult(String inputText);
}`

when you want to return the value to the main activity just impimint this method

`EditDialogListener activity = (EditDialogListener) getActivity();
 activity.receiveResult(YourEditText.getText().toString());`

now on your activity

`public class YourActivity extends Activity implements EditDialogListener`

add the `receiveResult` method

`` public void receiveResult(String str) {
       textReturned.setText(str);//set the value on an `editText` at your activity
 } ``

Comment: hai thank u,but i want to get result in adapter,not activity.actually i want to update a textview in adapter according to dialog fragment edittext valaue

Comment: its the same idea, implement the method on your adapter